# How to resize an iframe to trigger responsive breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, tailwind-css

I have the following component below but whenever I increase/decrease the size of the iframe, the responsive colors should change but they don't. Am I missing something?

Styling uses Tailwind

```js
export function Resizable() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(300);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <button className="" onClick={()=>setWidth(w=>w-=50)}>
        Decrease by 50
      </button>
      <button className="" onClick={()=>setWidth(w=>w+=50)}>
        Increase by 50
      </button>
      <iframe
        className="bg-red-300 sm:bg-yellow-300 md:bg-orange-300 lg:bg-purple-300 xl:bg-green-300 2xl:bg-blue-300"
        srcDoc={"<h1 className='text-red-100'>Resize me</h1>"}
        width={width}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the part where you have to `re-render` the component when the state changes. Right now, when the `width` state changes, the component doesn't `re-render` and the `CSS classes don't get updated.`

Try wrapping the iframe in a `div` and use `width` state to update the `style` attribute of that `div`.

---

**Try this code:**

```
export function Resizable() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(300);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <button className="" onClick={()=>setWidth(w=>w-=50)}>
        Decrease by 50
      </button>
      <button className="" onClick={()=>setWidth(w=>w+=50)}>
        Increase by 50
      </button>
      <div
        className="bg-red-300 sm:bg-yellow-300 md:bg-orange-300 lg:bg-purple-300 xl:bg-green-300 2xl:bg-blue-300"
        style={{width: `${width}px`}}
      >
        <iframe
          srcDoc={"<h1 className='text-red-100'>Resize me</h1>"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```